# Download Progress Calculator

Tags: java, android

Here is my progress calculator class. It is used for downloads/uploads. It takes bytes in and calculates the percentage(to the nearest 5%) that should show on a progress bar. Please let me know how I could improve it. Thanks a lot!!

```
public class ProgressCalculator {

    private int totalAmount;
    private int progressAmount;
    private int amountProgressItems;
    private int progressBarPercentage;

    //returns if the progress bar needs to change
    public boolean progress(int amount) {
        progressAmount = progressAmount + amount;
        return updateProgressbarPercentage();
    }

    public int getCurrentValue() {
        return progressBarPercentage;
    }

    //returns if the progressbar needs to change
    public boolean addProgressItem(int itemAmount) {
        totalAmount = totalAmount + itemAmount;
        amountProgressItems++;
        return updateProgressbarPercentage();
    }

    //returns true if has been updated;
    private boolean updateProgressbarPercentage() {
        int newProgressBarPercentage = round(calculateProgressPercentage());
        if (progressBarPercentage == newProgressBarPercentage) {
            return false;
        } else {
            progressBarPercentage = newProgressBarPercentage;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public int getAmountOfItems() {
        return amountProgressItems;
    }

    public boolean removeProgressItem(int byteAmount) {
        if (amountProgressItems > 0) {
            totalAmount = totalAmount - byteAmount;
            amountProgressItems--;
        }
        return updateProgressbarPercentage();
    }

    private int calculateProgressPercentage() {
        double x = progressAmount;
        double y = totalAmount;
        double result = (x / y) * 100;
        return (int) result;
    }

    private int round(int num) {
        int temp = num % 5;
        if (temp < 3)
            return num - temp;
        else
            return num + 5 - temp;
    }

    public void clear() {
        totalAmount = 0;
        progressAmount = 0;
        amountProgressItems = 0;
        progressBarPercentage = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really hard to tell what this class does. From what you say, I feel like you have a number of `TransferTask`s and want to have a sort of `ProgressTracker` for them. So, as for me, your goal is to make user's code look like this:

```
ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker();
progressTracker.setListener(new ProgressTrackerListener() {
  @Override
  public void onProgressChanged(double progressPercentage) {
    // TODO: update your UI here
  }
});
...
TransferTask transferTask = new UploadTask("/home/jiduvah/1.txt");
progressTracker.track(transferTask);
transferTask.start();
```

Why? Because it doesn't need any comments to describe what happens here: you just write it in English.

**Update** - In case you're absolutely sure you like your approach.

First, in this code:

```
private int round(int num) {
    int temp = num % 5;
    if (temp < 3)
        return num - temp;
    else
        return num + 5 - temp;
}
```

I see magic like `5` and `3`. Looks like it does exactly what you need to do, and you've even wrote about meaning of 5, but 3 is still a mystery.

Then:

```
double x = progressAmount;
double y = totalAmount;
double result = (x / y) * 100;
return (int) result;
```

When you divide `int` by `int`, you get `int`. When you divide `int` by `double` or `double` by `int`, you get `double`. So you may just write:

```
double result = 100 * progressAmount / (double)totalAmount;
```

Regarding the whole idea, I'm not sure whether this code works at all, because it's hard to understand how one should use it.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't so clear but you got it right. I have a number of transferTasks and I need to track the overall progress. It looks like a very logical way to do it. Is the maths side of it ok? I was unsure with casting the int from a double to work out the percentage. EDIT - never mind, it was answered below

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: with regards to the 3 and 5, Its rounding to the nearest 5%. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: http://ideone.com/pI4TN

Comment: I find the syntax a little hard to understand but the results are not what I want. I wanted to round to the nearest 5 not round up to the nearest 5. (nevertheless your help is much appreciated).

Comment: To get the same that you already have, fix like this: `quantizer * ((i + quantizer / 2) / quantizer)`, where quantizer is still 5.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that sticks out to me is `amountProgressItems`. Why do you need it?

It's only internal use is to prevent `removeProgressItem` from being called more times than `addProgressItem` was called. Furthermore, we do not have an guarantee that `remove` will be called with the same `byteAmount` parameters that `add` was called.

Personally, I would change these methods into `increaseTotalAmount(int)` and `decreaseTotalAmount(int)`.

All that said, if you have an external use for progress items, it's not *horrible*, so don't feel the need to change it.

---

One last thing, don't divide by zero, and `calculateProgressPercentage` can be one lined:

```
private int calculateProgressPercentage() {
    if(totalAmount == 0) return 0;
    return (int) (progressAmount * 100.0 / totalAmount);
}
```

Using `100.0` (not `100`) will result in the numerator being a double, causing the result to likewise be a double.

Comment: thanks for that, I up voted instead of marking correct as the other answer was a little more involved